# Открыть страницу Tomcat с другого компьютера в локальной сети

Tags: tomcat

На компьютере запущен Tomcat и я без проблем открываю страницы.
Но почему-то с другого компьютера в локальной сети не могу сделать то же самое, набрав в адресной строке: [http://адрес](http://%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81) компьютера:8080.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Везде решение данной проблемы описывают просто: введите [http://адрес](http://%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81) компьютера:8080 и всё заработает, но почему-то это не так.
Нашёл сообщение о том, что брандмауэр может блокировать, но, предполагаю, что если бы брандмауэр блокировал, то выдал бы об этом сообщение.
Но на всякий случай, и отключал брандмауэр, и создавал исключение, и "Разрешить другое приложение" - ничего не помогает.
В чём может быть причина, что я не могу с другого компьютера в локальной сети открыть страницу Tomcat, как найти эту причину и устранить?

Comment: а порт 8080 открыли?

Comment: Я не знаю, поэтому и спрашиваю, какие дополнительные действия нужно сделать. Даже ping не проходит:C:\Users\Админ>ping 192.168.56.1

Обмен пакетами с 192.168.56.1 по с 32 байтами данных:
Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.
Превышен интервал ожидания для запроса.

Статистика Ping для 192.168.56.1:
    Пакетов: отправлено = 4, получено = 0, потеряно = 4
    (100% потерь)